# Why do some APIs return data as a list of JSON rather than a JSON object?

Tags: json

Rather than returning

```
{email: 'example@example.com', firstName: 'john'}
```

instead you get

```
[{name: 'email', value: 'example@example.com'}, {name: 'firstName', value 'john'}]
```

I have noticed it in the HubSpot API and AWS Cognito SDK. It just makes it annoying to access a particular value because you need to loop through the objects to find the one you need.

Why is this done, is there some benefit I am unaware of?

Comment: You dont get a list of JSON you get JSON representing a list of objects

Comment: @NickA My terminology is a bit off sorry. The question is still valid right?

Comment: Maybe because some properties can have additional attributes (types, time,...)

Comment: @Tr1et I haven't seen that done before, but it's a good enough reason for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You get a JSON-array document instead JSON-object. It's OK and valid document. See more on [json.org](https://json.org).

The usual reason for this is when you want to return an iteratable set of similar (same type) elements - so it's array.